# Make a DIV slowly move offscreen

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I want to create a scoreboard where recent winners are listed.  When a new winner is announced, I want the three current winners to slide right, the new winner to slide from the left into place and the oldest winner (rightmost) to slide off screen.

With the code below, I have everything working except for the right side.  Right now, it just disappears (I want it to slide off the right side gracefully).

**HTML**

```
<div id="results-wrapper">
    <div class="contest-results" id="recent-winners">Recent winners:</div>
    <div class="contest-results" id="winner-wrapper">
        <div class="winner">John</div>
        <div class="winner">Katie</div>
        <div class="winner">Peter</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#results-wrapper {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 6px 3px 4px 3px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.contest-results {
    float:left;
}
#recent-winners {
    width: 120px;
    text-align: left;
}
#winner-wrapper {
    width: 444px;
    height: 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.winner {
    text-align: center;
    width: 148px;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
}
```

**JS**

```
$("#winner-wrapper").on("click", ".winner", function() {
    $('.winner:first').before('<div style="display: none;" class="winner">justin</div>');
    $('.winner').css({"display" : "inline", "left" : "-148px"});
    $('.winner').animate({"left" : "0px"}, {duration : 600, easing : "swing"});
    $('.winner:last').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is that using `float: left` essentially negates the effects of `white-space: nowrap`.

As stated in the entry for [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/float) from MDN:

> As `float` implicitly implies the use of the block layout, it modifies
>   the computed value of the `display` values in some cases

To perform the function you desire, first change the CSS property for `winner` to remove `float` and have `display: inline-block`.

```
.winner {
    text-align: center;
    width: 148px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Then modify the JavaScript to also deal with `inline-block` and remove the last winner only after the sliding animation is complete.

```
$("#winner-wrapper").on("click", ".winner", function () {
    var first = $(".winner").first();
    var last = $(".winner").last();
    first.before('<div style="display: none;" class="winner">justin</div>');
    $('.winner').css({
        "display": "inline-block",
        "left": "-148px"
    });
    $('.winner').animate({
        "left": "0px"
    }, {
        duration: 600,
        easing: "swing",
        complete: function () {
            last.remove();
        }
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ryn2S/)

[**ALTERNATE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9ALEy/) (with additional behaviors)

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
div {
  position:absolute;
  background-color:#abc;
  left:50px;
  width:90px;
  height:90px;
  margin:5px;
}
</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="left">&laquo;</button> <button id="right">&raquo;</button>
<div class="block"></div>

<script>
$("#right").click(function(){
  $(".block").animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "slow");
});

$("#left").click(function(){
  $(".block").animate({"left": "-=50px"}, "slow");
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

copied directly from http://api.jquery.com/animate/

50px is the distance that will be moved
slow is the speed (slow, medium, fast or you can enter a number of milliseconds)